# Displaying username in URL with header(...);

Tags: php, url, authentication, http-headers

I have a site that let's me login and displays a new form to post for posting an artcile once the user has logged in.

```
<?php
  if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
    if (empty($fetchedRows)) {
      echo "<p>Invalid username and/or password</p>";
    }
    else {
      echo "<p>Logged in</p>";
      header ('Location: index.php?user=' . $_POST['username']);
?>

    <form method="post" id="post-article">
    </form>

    <?php
    }
  }
?>
```

I want to have the username displayed in my URL. This works, however when I reach `header ('Location: index.php?user=' . $_POST['username']);`, the rest of the code won't run. It is supposed to display a new form if the user credentials are valid.

All of it works if I remove the `header(...);` line.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: there is a redirect using header. so the form not displays

Comment: Does it submit the username as well or do you get that out the database?

Comment: No, it checks the whether the DB returns any rows based on username and password input. If it returns a row, the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

put your form code on **index.php**

```
<form method="post" id="post-article">
    </form>
```

Comment: You mean the input tags etc? Those are already in. I just removed them before asking the question.

Comment: header is redirect function .so the page is redirected to index.php . You will see only index.php file when your condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are checking POST[username] and POST[password].
2. if everything is ok, you are redirecting it to the same location (index.php) with GET[user] (index.php?user=xxx)
3. It now comes to index.php, WITHOUT POST[username] and POST[password]. So it should display "Invalid username and/or password"

What you should do is, you should check $_SESSION[username] first. If it's empty it should check POST[username] and POST[password]. If all is ok you will do $_SESSION[username] = $_POST[username], then redirect.